# I can not build VLCJ. How do I build this?

Tags: lwjgl, vlcj

https://github.com/caprica/vlcj <- I got the VLCJ source code here and tried to build it using the "mvn package" command. However, the build fails. How do I collect?

vlc 64-bit is already installed. I also use windows 10 64 bit.

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project vlcj: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -> [Help1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException`

https://pastebin.com/5451CS88

Answer (score 0):

vlcj has a lot of test classes and they try and load the LibVlc native library. Your build, according to your posted log, is failing because those test classes can not find LibVlc when the tests execute.

If all you need to do is build vlcj, then just skip the tests in the standard way:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

But if you don't really need to *build* vlcj yourself, just use the Maven dependency as vlcj is available direct from the Maven Central repository.

To resolve the problem of why those tests are failing, you need to work out why LibVlc can't be found on your system.

The error message in your posted log gives you a number of things you can try to resolve this. The simplest thing to try is probably to set the "jna.library.path" property when you start your maven build, for example:

```
mvn clean install -Djna.library.path=<path-to-directory-that-contains-libvlc.dll>
```

You may also need to explicitly set the "VLC_PLUGIN_PATH" environment variable (this is NOT a Java system property) to the directory that contains the VLC plugins - on Windows this is usually a sub-directory called either "vlc" or "vlc/plugins".

If you set those values correctly and it still doesn't work, you need to make sure you have a 64-bit JVM and 64-bit VLC.

If you have this problem in your own application, ignoring the vlcj tests, then have a look at the Javadoc for the [NativeDiscovery](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.12.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/discovery/NativeDiscovery.html) class.

A brief foot-note, changes to the upcoming vlcj-4 should make this a lot easier for the vast majority of users.